# Degree of extension of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ with $S=\{ \sqrt3,\sqrt5\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

First time in abstract algebra, and right now I have some difficult to understand this example from one of my books.

How can I calculate the grade of extension of $\mathbb{Q}(S)$ with $S=\{ \sqrt3,\sqrt5\}$? If I extend $\mathbb{Q})$ with $\sqrt 3$ I have that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 3)$ minimum polynomial is $x^2-3$, but then what?

Thanks all

Comment: Grade$\mapsto$degree. The degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ is at most $4=2\times 2$, and it is exactly four since $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})$ and the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is biquadratic.

Comment: You will also need $\sqrt{15}$ to complete the field, so degree is 4.

Comment: Ok guys, but why we need to include $\sqrt 15$? This is in order to complete the field, not for the degree right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how to find the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, use @Jack D'Aurizio's comment. Otherwise prove that $x^2-5$ is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{5}$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$.